# Como selecionar o id da chave estrangeira na tabela principal?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
public List Select() { List ListaCaminhao = new List();

        SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(strCon);

        string sql = "Select * from Caminhao;";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexao);

        conexao.Open();

        try
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Model.Caminhao caminhao = new Model.Caminhao();

        caminhao.IDCaminhao = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0].ToString());

        caminhao.IDMotorista = convert.ToInt32(reader["IDMotorista"].ToString());
```

Este segundo `reader["IDMotorista"]` é a minha chave secundaria, é o id eu quero que mostre o nome.

Comment: É a mesma perguntar? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120793/91

Answer (score 2):

O que você precisa é um `JOIN`, para obter o nome do Motorista que esta na tabela secundaria.

```
Select C*, M.NomeMotorista from Caminhao C -- Corrija o M.NomeMotorista para seu campo
join Motorista M
on M.IDMotorista = C.IDMotorista  -- verifique o nome correto das chaves.
```

Você também vai precisar alterar sua classe `caminhao` com mais uma propriedade *NomeMotorista* .

```
caminhao.NomeMotorista = convert.ToInt32(reader["NomeMotorista "].ToString());
```

Comment: continuou aparecendo o id do motorista ainda .. bom vou pensar um pouco, mais obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: você executou direto no banco essa consulta?

Comment: não, foi na camada do meu desenvolvedor

Comment: como ficou depois do while (reader.Read())

Comment: Ficou a mesma coisa, não mudou nada ..

Comment: caminhao.IDMotorista = Convert.ToInt32(reader["IDMotorista"].ToString());
                    ListaCaminhao.Add(caminhao);
caminhao.nome = reader["nome"].ToString();
                    caminhao.km = Convert.ToInt32(reader["km"].ToString());
                    caminhao.modelo = reader["modelo"].ToString();
                    caminhao.qtde_eixo = Convert.ToInt32(reader["qtde_eixo"].ToString());
                    caminhao.tamanho = Convert.ToInt32(reader["tamanho"].ToString());

Comment: catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Deu erro na execução da seleção de Caminhão ...");
            }
            finally
            {
                conexao.Close();
            }
            return ListaCaminhao;
        }

Comment: Você adicionou o o reader do nome do motorista e fez o join?

Answer (score 1):

Substitua a linha:

```
string sql = "Select * from Caminhao;";
```

Por:

```
string sql = "SELECT c.*, m.nome AS nomemotorista FROM caminhao AS c
JOIN motorista AS m ON m.idmotorista = c.idmotorista";
```

Na sua 'Model.Caminhao' adicione também o atributo 'nomeMotorista';

Na linha:

```
 caminhao.IDMotorista = convert.ToInt32(reader["IDMotorista"].ToString());
```

Altere para:

```
caminhao.nomeMotorista = convert.ToInt32(reader["nomemotorista"].ToString());
```

Além disso, vocÊ também deverá alterar de 'caminhao.IDMotorista' para 'caminhao.nomeMotorista' lá onde vocÊ carrega sua lista pro elemento gráfico.

Comment: no meu caso o id está aparecendo como número na minha gridviwer, eu queria colocar o nome do meu motorista no lugar do número.. entendeu, se ajudar ..

Comment: Quais as colunas da sua tabela 'Caminhao' e da sua tabela 'motorista'?

Comment: tabela caminhao - idcaminhao, nome, km, modelo qtde_eixo, tamanho, idmotorista; tabela motorista - idmotorista, nome, idade, cpf, rg, endereco; são essas ai

Comment: Reveja a resposta. Creio que seja isso.